# Using the value of a textbox as a parameter for a datasource for a chklistbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2005, datasource, checklistbox

I have a login panel with a textbox for the userloginID. When the login button is clicked, the  datasource is supposed to pick up the valkue in the textbox and provide filtered data to the chklistbox dependent of the value in the userloginID textbox.

I only connect the datasource to the chklistbox when the login button is clicked, but the app still fal;ls over wit the folowing message:

> The Type property of parameter 'UserLogin' cannot be set when the
>   DbType property is set.  Description: An unhandled exception occurred
>   during the execution of the current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about the error and where it
>   originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The Type property
>   of parameter 'UserLogin' cannot be set when the DbType property is
>   set.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The Type property of parameter 'UserLogin'
>   cannot be set when the DbType property is set.]
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter.GetValue(Object value, Boolean
>   ignoreNullableTypeChanges) +1751307
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ParameterCollection.GetValues(HttpContext
>   context, Control control) +301
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.InitializeParameters(DbCommand
>   command, ParameterCollection parameters, IDictionary exclusionList)
>   +264    System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments) +472
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +95
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.PerformSelect() +34
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +73
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +82
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs
>   e) +22    System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs
>   e) +18    System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxList.OnPreRender(EventArgs
>   e) +20    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +80
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +842

Here is the Login buttons code (onclick):

```
Protected Sub btnLogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    If btnLogin.Text = "Login" Then
        btnLogin.Text = "Logout"
        PanelLogin.BackColor = Drawing.Color.LightGreen
        Me.CurrentUserLogin = Me.txtUserId.Text
        Me.chkLstClientcodes.DataBind()
        txtStatus.Text = "Logqed in as Andrew McLintock"
        'LoginSuccessInit()
        Me.chkLstClientcodes.DataSourceID = "clientcodes"
    Else
        btnLogin.Text = "Login"
        PanelLogin.BackColor = Drawing.Color.LightSalmon
        txtStatus.Text = "Not Logged In!!!"
    End If
    'Me.Page.Controls.Clear()
End 

    Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added logic to the underlying SQL that raised a flag if the row was valid in the context of the Report. Conditional formatting tested for that and changed the color.